# Angular 8 Cannot access 'PlanningModule' before initialization

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using the apex theme from themeforest. I am trying to acces the page: `/planning` However, the console shows a error:

```
core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: Cannot access 'PlanningModule' before initialization
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'PlanningModule' before initialization
    at Module.PlanningModule (planning.component.ts:12)
    at planning-layout.routes.ts:6
```

I don't have double initialization of the component nor the module. Only initialization is the service in `app.module`. Why did I get this error and how can I solve it?

App-routing.module.ts:

```
{
    path: 'planning',
    component: FullLayoutComponent,
    children: Planning_ROUTES,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
},
```

Planning.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {PlanningComponent} from './planning.component';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {DragulaModule} from 'ng2-dragula';
import {Ng2SmartTableModule} from 'ng2-smart-table';
import {NgSelectModule} from '@ng-select/ng-select';
import {PlanningRoutingModule} from './planning-routing.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PlanningComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    DragulaModule.forRoot(),
    Ng2SmartTableModule,
    NgSelectModule,
    PlanningRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class PlanningModule { }
```

Planning-routing.module.ts:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

import {PlanningComponent} from './planning.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PlanningComponent,
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class PlanningRoutingModule {
  constructor() {
    console.log('hier komt die(niet)');
  }
}
```

PlanningComponent.ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {PlanningService} from './planning.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-planning',
  templateUrl: './planning.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./planning.component.scss'],
})
export class PlanningComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router,
    private planningService: PlanningService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

Planning-routes.ts:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

export const Planning_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('../../pages/planning/index/planning.module').then(m => m.PlanningModule)
  },
];
```

Comment: Which Angular version are you using?

Comment: @LppEdd I am using Angular 8.2.2 but I just found out that ng2-dragula is the issue somehow.

Comment: How do you know it is the cause?

Comment: @LppEdd Because when I removed the import in the module, everything worked. Fixed the issue: forgot to add: ```(window as any).global = window;``` to ```polyfills.ts``` somehow I missed that while upgrading

Comment: So now everything is okay? Good!

Comment: Thanks a lot I ran into exactly the same problem. You saved me a lot of time.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem w/o ng2-dragula, any one else?

Answer (score 12):

This happens when you have a circular dependency between 1 or more Angular Modules.
I found it happens even if dependency is indirect, such as a service import. I'm assuming this has to do with initialization order.

For example -

This component has a dependency on a service defined in another module's subdirectory -

```
// declared in A_Module
export class A_Component implements OnInit {
//...
  constructor(
    private service: B_Service) {} // <-- dependency on B_Module??

}
```

```
// B_Module
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    A_Module // <-- dependency 
  ],
  exports: [],
  declarations: [...],
  providers: []
})
export class B_Module { }

// In B_Module sub-directory
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class B_Service {}
```

To resolve, I used an `Input()` binding in `A_Component`. One option might be to move the service under a shared module folder.

Comment: In addition to @Jeremy's answer, router guards must be ```@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })```. This is what got me.

Comment: I had a similar issue and I spent hours finding out the cyclic dependency. Finally, I found this tool which help me to find it. github.com/acrazing/dpdm#readme

Answer (score 0):

I still don't fully understand why I'm getting this error myself, but I was able to circumvent it with one of two solutions.

Firstly - and I don't expect this to be a fully comprehensive overview of my code - here's an overview:

1. I am generating a tree of dynamic components that use a custom injector.
2. That custom injector has a service `ConfigService` injected for each level in the tree.
3. The `ConfigService` is unique to each level in the tree.
4. There are other services that consume this `ConfigService` provided by the component.
5. I wanted to access an ancestor's `ConfigService` in a child node so I did this in my `SectionComponent`

   ```
    { provide: SECTION_CONFIG, useExisting: ConfigService }
   ```

And then in the child I inject `SECTION_CONFIG` as `parentSectionConfig: ConfigService`.

Unfortunately this is when I got the error which is purely an ES reference error with no Angular information. It *seems* to be occurring because I am using `useExisting` so something in that code path is trying to access something before it's created.

When Angular creates a component it has to figure out the correct order to create all the dependencies in and it seems I've managed to trip it up.

#### Solution 1:

I just created a sort of stub service to add an extra level of indirection:

```
providers: [
    ConfigServiceStub,  // create the stub
    { provide: SECTION_CONFIG, useExisting: ConfigServiceStub }
]
```

Or simply this (which is better):

```
providers: [
    { provide: SECTION_CONFIG, useClass: ConfigServiceStub }
]
```

The `ConfigServiceStub` is a service that injects ONLY `ConfigService` with a few private methods to return the important data from it.

This worked. The only difference is that extra level of indirection that the Angular compiler was able to now work with. Note that I am actually still using `useExisting` but it's now tagging onto a new service that is able to capture the correct dependencies.

And if you're reading all this and saying 'Well that doesn't make sense?' you're probably right and there's a lot more code I'm not including. But whatever it is I was able to fix it without really reorganizing anything. It doesn't seem like a circular reference because you can't fix a circular reference by adding another level of indirection.

#### Solution 2

Basically same solution, but using a factory:

```
 { provide: SECTION_CONFIG, useFactory: SectionConfigFactory, deps: [ ConfigService ] }

 export const SectionConfigFactory = (dep1: ConfigService) => dep1;
```

This also works and again isn't reorganizing anything in the component or .ts file graph - just adding a level of indirection for the sake it it.

The whole situation sounds like a bug to me in whatever algorithm is determining the order of things to create, but fortunately this workaround worked. Or it could perhaps be impossible due to the custom injector that injects services that my `SectionComponent` couldn't possibly know about at compile time.